# Workfront API: Human readable status for Issues and Projects

Tags: workfront-api

https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003574147-API-Basics
https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/categories/202718477

Querying objects (i.e.: GET /attask/api/v9.0/project/4c78821c0000d6fa8d5e52f07a1d54d0) returns a response similar to the following:

```
..
"status": "INP",
...
```

How do you get human readable statuses form these responses? Do you hard-code all possible values, or, can it be achieved using queries?

i.e.: "INP" > "In Progress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dictionary and translating the statuses while reading the short version (INP > In Progress)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull these values from the Custom Enumeration tables (CSTEM). For example, this will return all the task descriptions:

`https://subdomain.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/CSTEM/search?apiKey={{apiKey}}&fields=*&enumClass=STATUS_TASK&enumClass_Mod=in`

You will get something like this:

`{
            "color": "FF3939",
            "equatesWith": "CPL",
            "groupID": "5419c94f00004a056282a15eed58e47f",
            "label": "Complete",
            "objCode": "CSTEM",
            "value": "CPL",
            "ID": "57ed3a2000477cfb7368beb5d995bf88",
            "customerID": "540f5a3f0019b...",
            "description": "Task is fully completed",
            "enumClass": "STATUS_TASK",
            "extRefID": null,
            "isPrimary": true,
            "valueAsInt": null,
            "valueAsString": "CPL"
        },`

For issues use "STATUS_OPTASK".